# Unable to build sample project that comes with cocos2d-x 2.2.2

Tags: linux, cocos2d-x

I usually run on ArchLinux but understanding the fact that it is pretty difficult to set up cocos2d-x for arch I installed Ubuntu on my machine and the setup was easy but still cant build a project using the steps mentioned in the Documentation. I have googled a lot but was unable to find a similar issue anywhere.

I tried to build the project in linux as my first step to learn how to do things in cocos2d-x.

```
cd samples/Cpp/TestCpp/proj.linux/ && make -j5 DEBUG=1
```

But the build was interrupted by an error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `~/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/lib/linux/debug/libextension.a', needed by `bin/debug/TestCpp'. Stop.
```

I use cocos2d-x-2.2.2 that was available for download from their website to build the project. The TestCpp is a sample project that comes with cocos2d-x-2.2.2.zip that I downloaded from the site.

Any guidance that would help me to get up and coding will be appreciated.

Comment: I make project in android not in linux so if any need in proj.android then i can help you

Comment: Hmm. I thought that it would be better if I was able to test the project in linux machine itself than building for android everytime. But just realized building for linux requires similar effort as building for android. @Singhak the build process is working perfectly fine for android.